# Change default micrometer metrics tag

Tags: java, spring, prometheus, openlayers, micrometer

I would like to track http requests to my Spring Java server without creating custom metrics

Lets say I have this default micrometer metric

```
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/TMS/{L}/{Z}/{Y}/{X}",} 3.5174407
```

is it possible to change the `{L}` so it matches what was in the url, for example if someone calls `/TMS/OSM/3/4/4` it would be under

```
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/TMS/OSM/{Z}/{Y}/{X}",} 3.5174407
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Spring-Boot 3 app, you can add an `ObservationFilter` that adds the missing value. You will have access to the request and the `Obesrvation.Context` will also contain a high cardinality key-value called `url` that you can add as a low cardinality key-value.

Though, I would highly recommend against it since metrics should not have high cardinality tags, see here why: https://develotters.com/posts/high-cardinality/